# why biases change more frequent then weights?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorboard

I am visualizing biases and weights of fully connected part of my network.
I see that biases change more frequent then weights and I am trying to understand what does it mean.
In both cases I just took the weights and biases and presented them as histogram.

[image]

here we see:
 bias which is 1x256 parameters.
 weights which is matrix of 256X512 parameters.

Can be the reason that weight hardly change in visualization due to high number of numbers that just fall at the same bins ? can be better way to visualize the weight learning? or there some other reason.

Another part of the network that connects 16 neurons 1 neuron.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess this could be caused by gradient vanishing problem. If you look at the back-propagation algorithm you would see the gradient of weights is calculated by chain rule, for example, something like [this](https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/):

[image]

where

[image]
[image]

So, if the output values of last layer is very **close to 0**, the gradient of weights would also be closed to 0. As a result, the weights would not be updated with large magnitude. On the other hand, however, bias would not suffer from this problem, since the bias is not affected by previous layers during back-propagation.

You might search online to see the causes of gradient vanishing problem if you aren't familiar with it.

Comment: I have batch normalization with those layers and in addition my activation function is elu. I really not sure how I can suffer from vanishing gradients

Comment: have you normalised your input? @NightWalker

Comment: my input is not normalized, the input is images and I am feeding them into network as I receive them.

Comment: @NightWalker just try `img /= 255.` if it's RGB of 0-255

Comment: with normalization same story nothing changed.